# Number of generator in the finite field

Tags: finite-fields

Our material defines generator like below.

> Sometimes it is easier to define the elements of the $GF(2^n)$ field
>   using a generator.   $\{0,g,g,g^2,...,g^N\}$, where $N=2^n-2$

But I cannot understand why $N=2^n-2$ not $2^n-1$.
If $n=3$, $GF(2^3)$ has 8 elements but generators are 7 including zero. Why?

Comment: @Wuestenfux Be careful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing $g^0$ from your counting. It's $\{0,g^0,g,g^2,...,g^N\}$ (you had $g$ twice here instead of $g^0$). If $N = 2^n-2$, then there are $2^n-1$ different powers of $g$, and a $0$ for $2^n$ elements in total.

To take the $2^3$ example, there are (if you choose $g$ wisely) $7$ distinct powers of $g$ in $GF(8)$:
$$
g^0, g, g^2, g^3, g^4, g^5, g^6
$$
If we include $0$, that makes it $8$ elements in total.

Comment: clear explanation